# Creating a spy on onChange method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine

I have the following:

```
    handleChange: function(e) {
                        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
                    },
................
...............<input type="text".... onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

How can i test whether onChange has been called with `toHaveBeenCalled()` when user enters/changes characters ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work just fine?

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  this.toHaveBeenCalled();
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
},

<input type="text".... onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to monitorize a state change would be `console.log()` ..